# Algorithm: Memorizing a drawing

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, drawing

I'm not going to turn the images into files yet (and I don't know if I'm ever going to do this).

The drawings are made by a custom-made drawing program (where the user draws). When I resize the application, the drawing disappears, because it's not being redrawn. And that's because the image is not being memorized in any way. I need an algorithm for memorizing the drawing, so it can be redrawn after the whole application refreshes.

One algorithm I thought of is to memorize the location and color every pixel. But I don't think this is a good idea.

I'm currently using Java, but I need a language-agnostic algorithm. Still, I would accept a solution explained with code.

What algorithm should I use for memorizing the whole drawing?

Comment: What kind of drawings is it? vector drawing with only line segments or Bézier curves can be easily saved and redrawn at any scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of options. One is, as you say, to remember the image pixels. You can also simply remember all the user actions that generated the drawing and replay them when you need to reconstruct the drawing.

Another approach, depending on the tools that the drawing program offers the user, would be to build a more compact representation of the image. For instance, if the drawing program only offered the possibility of drawing lines, you could remember the set of line endpoints (and colors, line thicknesses, and whatever other line data was relevant). This generalizes in an obvious way to a larger set of geometric primitives.

For free-hand drawing, you can remember the stroke paths along with whatever stroke settings were set at the time. Depending on the complexity of the stroke tools your program offers, this may end up being more data than simply remembering the drawing pixels. However, it does allow, for instance, scaling the drawing if the canvas expands.

Comment: Which solution do you think is the faster when refreshing the image?

Comment: @AlekZanDer - It depends on the implementation details, but I would think a copy of the image pixels will be fastest. Instead of drawing directly on the screen, draw to a bitmap and draw the bitmap to the screen.

Comment: You say "_When I resize the application ... so it can be redrawn after the whole application refreshes._"  So the best answer is a vector system of some sort - SVG, PNG, or as @TedHopp says, remember the strokes or endpoints.

Comment: @RossPatterson - It depends, of course, on whether the image is supposed to resize along with the application. It may be, for instance, that enlarging the application is meant to add canvas area to extend the drawing, and reducing the size of the application is meant to crop the image. OP hasn't said.

Answer (score 3):

You could memorize the user's actions: for example, if s/he draws a line, then memorize the starting and ending address. If s/he draws handsfree a drawing, then you memorize the single pixels (you have to!).

This allows to resize, rotate, etc. any drawing by just manipulating the coordinates.

The "drawing" becomes then a list of actions:

```
{
    LINE_DRAWING,
    x1, y1, x2, y2,
    pen, color, thickness...
}
{
    ...
}
```

To redraw, just scan the same list and call again the appropriate subroutines. Depending on the language, you can represent the list as an array, a linked list, a doubly linked list, and implement things such as element deletion.

On file, I would suggest some sort of tagged format:

```
two bytes - element type
four bytes - this element's length
variable-size data depending on element type
```

Again, to "load" the drawing you just scan the file sequentially and populate the memory structures.

You can google 'vector drawing' for more details and hints.